# Objective-C GLSL mix() equivalent

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, glsles

I`m trying to figure out how to write a equivalent to GLSL(ES)s mix method. I tried to add/divide rgb Values but with no luck yet. Any pointer to how the GLSL method works would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mix` in GLSL does a linear combination of its two inputs, based on a scaling factor that ranges in [0,1].  From the [GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/glsl/):

```
T mix ( T x, T y, T2 a )
{
    return (1-a)*x + a*y;
}
```

where `T` represents any valid vector or scalar type in GLSL capable of being modulated by a scalar value (e.g., vec2, mat4, etc.).  `T2` is either a floating-point type (i.e., `float` or `double`), or the type matching `T`, in which case `a` is applied component-wise to the components of `x` and `y`.